# Android localization based on folder "values"

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a simple question about localization in android.

I have read in the android documentation that to localize the string of an app, you need to create localized values folder, for example:

```
values/strings.xml
values-it/strings.xml
values-en/strings.xml
values-fr/strings.xml
```

and put every string in every file..

But ... my question is, if the folder structure is like the one I wrote and  open the app with a German or Spanish Smartphone, what strings.xml will be loaded? `/values/strings.xml` correct? Or do i have to set somewhere else that `/values/` have to be the default folder?

I think this is not specified in the android documentation.

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify /values/strings.xml as default folder, and it actually **is** specified in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html), which says:

> Whenever the application runs in a locale for which you have not provided locale-specific text, Android will load the default strings from res/values/strings.xml. If this default file is absent, or if it is missing a string that your application needs, then your application will not run and will show an error

Answer (score 0):

If current locale is does not have specific `values-languageCode` folder, default `strings.xml` will be used. That is `values/strings.xml`